# Finding all polynomial solutions to the IVP $y^{\prime}=f(x)/g(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question: Let $f: I_1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:I_2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two functions. Let $x_0 \in I_1$ and $y_0 \in I_2$ such that $g(y_0)=0$.
Find solutions $y:I_1 \longrightarrow I_2$ to the IVP:  $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$, $y(x_0)=y_0$.

Solution: Let $\int g(y)dy=G(y)$ and $\int f(x)dx=F(x)$. So, my solution to the ODE is G(y)=F(x)+c and since $g(y_0)=0 \implies G(y_0)=d$ which is some constant. Also, let $f=goy$ then, $f(x_0)=g(y(x_0))=0$ so, $F(x_0)=d$, hence, $c=0$. So, we have $G(y)=F(x)$.

What am I doing wrong? I am very confused with my solution.

Comment: @Gonçalo even I do not get that. As you pointed out in your answer below, I get my c=0 as well but I just don't know where to go with the solution. I mean in a way the solution is saying that $x=F^{-1}(G(y))$ which is just all functions for which $y$ is defined....